# insert into mysql from a while loop not working

Tags: php, loops

I have a database of users access_token and I made code makes sure that if a new user access token already exist in the database it should show an error  I tried to make a loop and put if statement inside it but its not working.

```
<?php

mysql_connect("localhost", "___", "___");
mysql_select_db("___");
session_start();

require_once ('twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php');
require_once ('config.php');

if (empty($_SESSION['access_token']) || 
    empty($_SESSION['access_token']['oauth_token']) || 
    empty($_SESSION['access_token']['oauth_token_secret'])) {
  header('Location: ./clearsessions.php');
}

$access_token = $_SESSION['access_token'];
$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, 
                               CONSUMER_SECRET,
                               $access_token['oauth_token'],
                               $access_token['oauth_token_secret']);
$content = $connection->get('account/verify_credentials');
$u = "SELECT * FROM users";
$uu = mysql_query($u);

while ($uuu = mysql_fetch_object($uu)) 
{
  foreach($uuu->access_token as $ali)
  {
    if ($access_token['oauth_token'] != $ali)
    {
      $newuser = "INSERT INTO users(access_token,access_token_secret)
                  VALUES ('{$access_token['oauth_token']}',
                          '{$access_token['oauth_token_secret']}' )";
      $donewuser = mysql_query($newuser);
      include ('html.inc');
    }
    else
    {
      echo "error";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: you could at least format the code for us to read?

Comment: Hey, what do u mean by format the code? I think the code is very clear :)

Comment: What isn't working? The loop? The insertion? The connection?

Comment: none of the code work but when I take the while of the code it works perfectly

Comment: Your code is full of bad practices try to avoid them, is there any error messages?

Comment: No, it shows me just white page

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign your connection to a variable otherwise it isn't actually doing anything.

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost','user','password');
mysql_select_db('database_name', $link);

*snip*

$uu = mysql_query($u, $link);
```

Also, please, please don't use mysql functions as they are deprecated. You should be using either [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [Mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Comment: Im pretty sure OP removed credential on purpose and used `__` as placeholders

Comment: Yeah, I know. In the absence of actual values, I've mimicked the format given in the question.

Comment: well it could be, I would be surprised a programmer would make such mistake but true its possible

Comment: guys I am struggling with this problem, can u guys help me please :(

Comment: or how can I fetch all the data from the database then store it inside a variable?

Comment: Have you tried what I suggested in my answer with regards to the way you're connecting to and then selecting the database?